# Mathematica 10.3 Dsolve solving a simple PDE

Tags: differential-equations

I tried to use **Mathematica 10.2** and **10.3** to solve this simple ***PDE*** and I want to a general solution. But it seems not working.
**DSolve** has been improved in v10.3. But we see it's perhaps not improved enough.

```
eq = (x - y)*D[f[x, y], x, y] - D[f[x, y], x] + D[f[x, y], y] == 0;
DSolve[eq, f[x, y], {x, y}]
(*  ? :(  *)
```

General solution is:
$$f(x,y)=\frac{c_2(x)+c_1(y)}{x-y}$$

If we assume that `C1[y]=y` and `C2[x]=x` then:

```
f[x_, y_] := (y + x)/(x - y);
(x - y)*D[f[x, y], x, y] == D[f[x, y], x] - D[f[x, y], y]
(*True*)
```

Comment: And the question is...?

Comment: [The documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DSolveSecondOrderPDEs.html) clearly states that this equation does not belong to a class of PDEs that Mathematica can solve.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries. I am very disappointed  with Mathematica that can't solve very simple equations.

Comment: Second order PDEs are not simple equations in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Often, `DSolve` can make progress when given a little help.  Even without knowing the solution, it is plausible to make the substitution, `f[x, y] -> g[x, y]/(x - y)`, in order to eliminate the `(x - y)` term from the ODE.

```
(Unevaluated[(x - y)*D[f[x, y], x, y] - D[f[x, y], x] + 
    D[f[x, y], y]] /. f[x, y] -> g[x, y]/(x - y)) // Simplify
(* Derivative[1, 1][g][x, y] *)
DSolve[% == 0, g[x, y], {x, y}]
(* {{g[x, y] -> C[1][x] + C[2][y]}} *)
```

Comment: Good Trick :) .How many tricks I need to know ?